# Proof that no set (under the ZFC) contains itself.

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

## Introduction

Let us denote the axioms (only those which we'll need below) of [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory):

- A.R. : Axiom of Regularity
- A.U. : Axiom of Union
- A.P. : Axiom of Pairing
- A.S. : Axiom schema of Specification

Using these axioms it is quite easy to show that the following set
$$
x \in x,\quad \text{i.e.}\quad x= \{..., x,...\}
$$
cannot exist. Indeed
$$
\big[\exists x\big( x\in x\big)\big] \Rightarrow \text{A.P.+A.S} \Rightarrow \big[\exists M = \{x\}\big] \Rightarrow \big[\forall m \in M(m\cap M \neq \emptyset)\big] \Rightarrow \big[\neg \text{A.R}\big]
$$
But what if we don't restrict $x$ to contain itself ''directly'' i.e. let's allow $x$ be the following ''set'':
$$
x \big( \exists a_{1}, a_{2}, ...,a_{n} \big( x \in a_{1} \in a_{2} \in ...\in a_{n} \in x\big)\big)
$$
in other words
$$
x = \{... \{...x...\}...\}
$$
Well, this is a bad ''set'' because AFAIK ZFC forbids infinitely decreasing sequences under $\in$. So I and my colleague have proved (no big deal, but anyway) that such a set cannot exist too:
$$
\big[\exists x\big( \exists a_{1} \in ... \in a_{n} \big(x \in a_{1}, a_{n} \in x\big)\big)\big] \Rightarrow \text{A.P. + A.S. + A.U.} \Rightarrow \big[\exists Y = \{x,a_{1}, ..., a_{n}\}\big] \Rightarrow \big[\forall y \in Y(y\cap Y \neq \emptyset)\big] \Rightarrow \big[\neg \text{A.R}\big]
$$

## Problem

In the proof above we used the fact that there was a *countable* (and even finite) sequence of $a_i$. But what if it was an *infinite* (and possibly *uncountable*) sequence of $a_i$ with the mentioned property. Would our proof work anyway? The problem is *how to construct the set $Y$ in this case*? Is it a right direction to prove the desired result?

### Update

#### 1. The desired property

The property I meant was
$$ x\in a_{1} \in a_{2} \in ... \in a_{n} \in x $$

Comment: What would it mean to have an infinite sequence of $a_i$ "with the mentioned property"? The property only seems to make sense for finite sequences.

Comment: Could you introduce your proof to see your argument works for general cases?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the "desired property". But my question still remains: How do you intend to generalize this to an infinite sequence?

Answer (score 1):

> In the proof above we used the fact that there was a countable (and even finite) sequence ... But what if it was an infinite (and possibly uncountable) sequence ... with the mentioned property.

What exactly is the mentioned property? If the mentioned property is $a_0∈a_1∈...$, then one can show that this is impossible in ZFC regardless of the length of the sequence.(show that if $(b_i)$ is a sequence, then there exists a set $\{b_i\}$ whose elements are exactly the element of the sequence, then this shows that there exists a $\{a_i\}$ and indeed this set proves ¬A.R.)

---

But if the "mentioned properties" is "the other direction", i.e.
there exists $x$, such that there exists $a_0∈x$, and there exists $a_1∈a_0$ and so on, we only have "finite levels".

By that I mean that if I have a set $x$, then we have the elements that are inside of $x$; those are "0 levels deep".

We have the elements that are inside the elements that are inside $x$(e.g. $a∈b∈x$), those are "1 level deep".

We can continue for each **finite** level, but there is no infinite level; what does it even mean to have "infinite level deep"?

Because it only makes sense to talk about finite levels, there is no meaning to talk about infinite sequences.(As a side note, the collection of all sets $a$ that are in some level from $x$ is called the transitive closure of $x$, denoted as $TC(x)$, and this collection is in fact a set)

Answer (score 0):

$\sf ZF$ proves the existene of a [transitive closure](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Transitive_Closure_(Set_Theory)#Definition) set for every set $x$, usually denoted by $\text{TrCl}(x)$

Using your terminology assume that:

$$
x = \{... \{...x...\}...\}
$$

Or as you wrote:

$$
x \in a_1 \in a_2 \in ... \in a_n \in x
$$

Then this translates to saying that: $x \in \text{ TrCl} (x)$

Now using separation construct the set $K(x)$ of all elements $y$ of $\text {TrCl}(x)$ such that $x \in \text{ TrCl}(y)$. Thus $\Rightarrow [\neg \text{A.R}]$, since every $y$ would have one of its elements having $x$ in its transitive closure thus would be an element of $K(x)$ also.